# 123-Reg domain and email with linode hosting

Tags: email, dns, web-hosting, linode

I have a domain www.mydomain.co.uk and it is registered with 123-reg.co.uk. The nameservers in the 123-reg control panel are set to:

```
ns1.linode.com
ns2.linode.com
ns3.linode.com
ns4.linode.com
```

I am under the impression that setting the nameservers to my linode then make the 123-reg (A, MX, CNAME, TXT, SRV) settings redundant and they should now be set using my linode DNS manager?

In my linode I have the following settings for domain zone: 
mydomain.co.uk

```
SOA Record
========================
Primary DNS: ns1.linode.com
Email: contact@mydomain.co.uk
Rest of settings: Default

NS Records
========================
Name Server: ns1.linode.com, ns2.linode.com, ns3.linode.com, ns4.linode.com, ns5.linode.com
subdomain: mydomain.co.uk
TTL: Default

MX Records
========================
Mail Server: mx0.123-reg.co.uk
Preference: 10
Subdomain: 
TTL: Default

Mail Server: mx1.123-reg.co.uk
Preference: 20
Subdomain: 
TTL: Default

A/AAAA Records
========================
Hostname: 
IP Address: xxx.xx.xxx.xx
TTL: Default

Hostname: design
IP Address: xxx.xx.xxx.xx
TTL: Default

Hostname: mail
IP Address: xxx.xx.xxx.xx
TTL: Default

Hostname: www
IP Address: xxx.xx.xxx.xx
TTL: Default

CNAME Records
========================
None

TXT Records
========================
None

SRV Records
========================
None
```

With these settings, I am able to send emails via the 123-reg webmail client to my personal hotmail and can also receive emails sent from my hotmail. What I am stuck on, is if I try to send an email from the 123-reg webmail, to that same email address, it never gets received though the email is there in the sent box.

I'm not too clued up on all this so I don't really even know where to look, I was hoping to supply as much detail as I can in the hope that someone might know why my email cannot receive messages it sends to itself?

Thank you so much for reading this, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My name is karra I work here at 123-Reg.

I have read your post and have tried to replicate your reported issue from my own personal account and have been unable to do so.

I would like to help you further to try and help resolve this, could you send me across your domain name or username to onlinesupport@123-reg.co.uk so I can locate your account.

Regards